# overlay image - Camera - iOS

Tags: image, cocoa-touch, camera

I could not find anything on how to do this type of functionality with the camera.

anyone have any idea where to start looking?  what library to use?

when I'm taking the picture the image is this

[image]

then gets this way when saved.

[image]

the picture is just an example.

I'll use a static logo on the right and below.

is just that.

Tanks.